# How to enable auto commit in Intellij idea for oracle db

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij idea to connect to oracle db and postgresql.
For postgresql auto commit is set so every time I run an insert statement the data immediately commits. However, for oracle auto commit is not set so I have to write both my statement and COMMIT WORK statement. That is quit inconvenient, so I want to enable auto commit for oracle as well.
I was unable to find a special button or switch for that.

So where is the button that can turn auto commit on and off or is there any sql command for that?

P.S. I know that some other tolls for db such as DBeaver have this feature but I'm asking specificly about Intellij idea.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-database-connections.html#transaction-mode ?

Answer (score 0):

**Session Level Approach**

Here is the SQL command that you can use before executing any procedure or DML command

```
 autocommit on;
```

---

**Machine Wide Approach**

Alternatively, for enabling auto-commit machine-wise, you can edit `"$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql"` and set `"SET AUTOCOMMIT ON"` in that file if you are using SQL*Plus connector

---

**IntelliJ Specific Approach**

Another approach would be to inject `set autocommit on` into **startup script** under **Data Sources and Drivers dialog - Options**